# Combining seaborn barplot with matplotlib.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to add a plot to a sns.barplot.
It seems to screw up the axis when I add the plt.plot()

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
_, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)

g = sns.barplot( IND.index, IND.NID_NGDP, color = sns.color_palette("Set1", 10)[3])
g = sns.barplot(IND.index, IND.NGSD_NGDP, color = sns.color_palette("Set1", 10)[1])
g.set_ylabel('% of GDP')

ax2 = g.twinx()
#ax2.set_ylabel('% CA balance',color='b')
ax2.plot(IND.index,IND.BCA_NGDPD,label='CA Deficit (right axis)')
```

This gives me the following chart:

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLUeY.png)

I want something like this with the line for IND.BCA_NGDPD drawn across it

[What I hope to get .. plus a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5TPx.png)

Comment: Never mind! Fixed. I just needed:    ax2.plot(g.get_xticks(),IND.BCA_NGDPD,label='CA Deficit (right axis)')

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Sorry... I just needed to change the last line to:

```
ax2.plot(g.get_xticks(),IND.BCA_NGDPD,label='CA Deficit (right axis)')
```